# How to call custom functions from models.py django

Tags: python, django

I'm building a custom function to pull the data from `mongodb` and want to see the data what it is look like before the manipulation.

say I have a function to request the data from `mongodb`

Here is how my models.py looks like

```
from bson import json_util
from django.db import models
from django.http import JsonResponse
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.json_util import loads
import json
import pymongo

def data_pull(request):
     request_data = request.POST.get('Hello', None) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_pull(request)
```

to run the models.py I do `python models.py` from the command line but getting this error

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

So basically I want to test this `data_pull` function from models.py and see that what the data looks like. How can I feed this `request` call into the function and see the output from commandline?

Comment: The HTTP request usually only exists in the views (in the context of the HTTP request-response cycle)

Comment: How do you call the function? If from a view, then you can pass the request as a parameter to the function

Comment: @Ralf thank for response. Yes I'm calling it from views.py

Comment: @Ralf do you mean if just to python views.py call with if __name__=='main' at the bottom of views.py I should be fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code seems strange:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_pull(request)
```

Usually, if you pass a `request` as argument, you would call the function `data_pull()` from a view and pass the request as an argument in the function call.

You cannot just use `if __name__ == "__main__":` and expect a request object to appear, you need to create one yourself or use the request object that is created by the views (the django engine takes care of if for the most part).

More info in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#quick-overview

---

EDIT: if you want a `HttpRequest` object, that usually means that you want the data that is sent from a webbrowser (the data that the django engine places inside `request.GET` and `request.POST` and others). That means that you should probably call you function `data_pull()` from a view.

For example this code in your 'views' file (code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

# since you function is declared in 'models', we import it here
from .models import data_pull

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # call the function passing request as argument
        data_pull(request)

        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Comment: Can you give more intuituve picture what needs to be done based on the original question asked.  I tried to call the function in views.py to make a request from models.py but still it did not worked. Can you explain what did you mean about `you need to create one yourself or use the request object that is created by the views` ?

Comment: @Alexander ok, I tried to explain it differently